# print(raw_message['altitude']) TypeError

Tags: python

I have tried on all forums how to fix this error, but I do not understand what I'm doing wrong.
If you can give me a hand you do me a big favor, thank you very much.
Want to clarify that I looked for solutions for all and this post is my last chance

Error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 35, in <module>
    client.run(callback=process_beacon, autoreconnect=True)
  File "/Users/gionatadonati/Desktop/python-ogn-client/ogn/client/client.py", line 74, in run
    callback(packet_str)
  File "test2.py", line 29, in process_beacon
    print(raw_message['altitude'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Code:

```
from ogn.client import AprsClient
from ogn.parser import parse, ParseError


def inRange_square(s, minLat, maxLat, minLon, maxLon, minAlt, maxAlt):
    if s.get('longitude', 0) < minLon or s['longitude'] > maxLon or s['latitude'] < minLat or s['latitude']>maxLat or s['altitude']<minAlt or s['altitude']>maxAlt :

        return False

    return True


def processPlane(plane):
    #if(inRange_square(plane, 46.158593, 46.166797, 8.891647, 8.869160, 210, 1000)):
    if(inRange_square(plane, 46.127356, 46.441491, 9.276551, 8.460816, 210, 1000)):
        print("The plane is in range")
        print('Received  {raw_message}'.format(**beacon))
    else:
        #print("The plane is not in range")
        'odd'

def process_beacon(raw_message):
   try:
       beacon = parse(raw_message)
       #print('Received  {raw_message}'.format(**beacon))
       processPlane(beacon)
   except ParseError as e:
       print('Error, {}'.format(e.message))
       print(raw_message['altitude'])

client = AprsClient(aprs_user='N0CALL')
client.connect()

try:
    client.run(callback=process_beacon, autoreconnect=True)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\nStop ogn gateway')
    client.disconnect()
```

Output of `print(raw_message)`:

```
RND000000>APRS,qAS,EKHG:/131942h6505.31S/18136.75W^054/325/A=002591 !W31! idA4000000 +099fpm +1.8rot FL029.04 21.5dB 4e +1.6kHz gps11x17
```

Comment: Would you please spend minimal effort on reducing offensive words in your code? Thanks!

Comment: what is the output of `print(raw_message)`? and the `type(raw_message)`

Comment: Yes, sorry about that...

Comment: @GionataDonati if you put `print(raw_message)` underneath `def process_beacon(raw_message)` what's the output

Comment: this: RND000000>APRS,qAS,LOGK:/135642h6505.31S/18136.75W^054/325/A=002591 !W31! idA4000000 +099fpm +1.8rot FL029.04 48.2dB 11e -16.5kHz gps11x17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to do

```
print( raw_message['altitude'] )
```

and getting the error message

```
string indices must be integers
```

So, the logical conclusions is that `raw_message` is a String, not a dictionary. You can use `raw_message['altitude']` to get the `altitude` key of a dictionary, but a String doesn't have keys - only indices.

Additionally, keep in mind *where* this error is occurring. It's inside of an `except` block, and specifically only runs when you can't parse a raw message (and I'm assuming that the "raw message" is, indeed, just a regular string of text).

Try doing

```
print( raw_message )
```

instead for the debug information you need. Or, at least, treat it as a string instead of as a dictionary. It's possible that the real cause of your error is that `parse(raw_message)` is throwing an error and it's not supposed to, in which case you might want to do step-by-step debugging with a tool like PDB to figure out where it's failing.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will keep in mind.
Thanks for the solution and for your valuable advice.